# using classic asp for regular expression

Tags: regex, asp-classic

We have some Classic asp sites, and i'm working on them a lil' bit, and I was wondering how can I write a regular expression check, and extract the matched expression:

the expression I have is in the script's name
so Let's say this

```
Response.Write Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
```

Prints out:

```
review_blabla.asp
review_foo.asp
review_bar.asp
```

How can I get the `blabla`, `foo` and `bar` from there?

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using, VBscript or JScript?

Comment: looks like VBScript. God have mercy with his soul.

Comment: it's a very old site and unfortunately, we don't have time to rewrite the whole thing

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Whilst Yots' answer is almost certainly correct, you can achieve the result you are looking for with a lot less code and somewhat more clearly:

```
'A handy function i keep lying around for RegEx matches'
Function RegExResults(strTarget, strPattern)

    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = strPattern
    regEx.Global = true
    Set RegExResults = regEx.Execute(strTarget)
    Set regEx = Nothing

End Function

'Pass the original string and pattern into the function and get a collection object back'
Set arrResults = RegExResults(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"), "review_(.*?)\.asp")

'In your pattern the answer is the first group, so all you need is'
For each result in arrResults
    Response.Write(result.Submatches(0))
Next

Set arrResults = Nothing
```

Additionally, I have yet to find a better [RegEx playground than Regexr](https://regexr.com/), it's brilliant for trying out your regex patterns before diving into code.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the Submatches Collection from the Match Object to get your data out of the `review_(.*?)\.asp` Pattern

```
Function getScriptNamePart(scriptname)
    dim RegEx : Set RegEx = New RegExp
    dim result : result = ""
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "review_(.*?)\.asp"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    Dim Match, Submatch
    dim Matches : Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(scriptname)    
    dim SubMatches
    For Each Match in Matches
        For Each Submatch in Match.SubMatches
                result = Submatch
        Exit For
        Next
    Exit For
    Next

    Set Matches = Nothing
    Set SubMatches = Nothing
    Set Match = Nothing
    Set RegEx = Nothing

    getScriptNamePart = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
review_(.*?)\.asp
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u7c3)

You will then find your result in capture group 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp object to do so.
Your code gonna be like this:

```
Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
RegularExpressionObject.Pattern = "review_(.*)\.asp"
matches = RegularExpressionObject.Execute("review_blabla.asp")
```

Sorry, I can't test code below right now.
Check out usage at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx