# Detect quote ("), single quote (') and comma in string

Tags: forms, vbscript, asp-classic, passwords

I need to make sure a person's password meets specific criteria before they can continue creating their account. I would like to add a statement checking for `'`, `"`, and `,`. The application is in VBScript. This is what I have so far. I cannot find anything on the web.

```
IsComplex = True

'Check Length
If Len(cPassword) < 8 Then
    IsComplex = False
End If

'Check for lowercase letters
HasLowerCase = False
For x = 97 to 122
    If Instr(4,cPassword,chr(x)) > 0 Then
        HasLowerCase = True
    End If
Next
If HasLowerCase = False Then
    IsComplex = False
    cForceChange = "E"
End If

'Check for uppercase letters
HasUpperCase = False
For x = 65 to 90
    If Instr(1,cPassword,chr(x)) > 0 Then
        HasUpperCase = True
    End If
Next
If HasUpperCase = False Then
    IsComplex = False
    cForceChange = "E"
End If

'Check for numbers
HasNumber = False
For x = 48 to 57
    If Instr(1,cPassword,chr(x)) > 0 Then
        HasNumber = True
        cForceChange = "E"
    End If
Next
If HasNumber = False Then
    IsComplex = False
    cForceChange = "E"
End If
```

Comment: Use Regex [(info)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) [(usage)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675920/using-classic-asp-for-regular-expression) - it's far more useful in this respect.

Comment: Thanks will look into this next time, would much rather just add a statement to this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for them literally:

```
If InStr(cPassword, "'")  > 0 Then  ' Single-quote found
If InStr(cPassword, """") > 0 Then  ' Double-quote found (need to use TWO quotes)
If InStr(cPassword, ",")  > 0 Then  ' Comma found
```

The only tricky one is the double-quote (`"`). Since VBScript uses this for string literals, you must escape it (by using two of them) when you need to refer to it within a string literal.